# Code approval by all listed contributors before merge

Tags: github

We have an organization on GitHub that has three contributors. However, we would like to make sure that all changes committed to the codebase in the repositories are approved by all (or a majority) of the owners.

In the past the code in a particular repository was changed before it could be reviewed by the rest of the team. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure that in the repository's settings under the **"Branches"** option.

Specify whatever suits your needs under **"Branch name pattern"** field and enable **"Require pull request reviews before merging"**. You can then set it up the way you want it to be with the modifier controls there are available.

[image]